# Soap Response not showing child objects

Tags: integration, soapui, synchronous, maximo, inbound

Need help! I'm having a problem with soap response, the child object in the object structure is not showing on the response. The parent object is 'PO' and the child object is 'MATRECTRANS'.

Here is my request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <max:SyncX1PO>
         <max:X1POSet>
            <max:PO action="AddChange">
               <max:SITEID>BEDFORD</max:SITEID>
               <max:PONUM>TEST9</max:PONUM>
               <max:REVISIONNUM>0</max:REVISIONNUM>
               <max:MATRECTRANS>
                 <max:POLINE>1</max:POLINE>
                 <max:ITEMNUM>1234</max:ITEMNUM>
                 <max:RECEIPTQUANTITY>2.00</max:RECEIPTQUANTITY>
               </max:MATRECTRANS>
               <max:MATRECTRANS>
                 <max:POLINE>2</max:POLINE>
                 <max:ITEMNUM>5411</max:ITEMNUM>
                 <max:RECEIPTQUANTITY>2.00</max:RECEIPTQUANTITY>
              </max:MATRECTRANS>
            </max:PO>
         </max:X1POSet>
      </max:SyncX1PO>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the response, where the child object is missing:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <SyncX1POResponse creationDateTime="2018-03-26T14:03:34+08:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="3381994.1522044214139897215" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <X1POSet>
            <PO>
               <SITEID>BEDFORD</SITEID>
               <PONUM>TEST9</PONUM>
               <REVISIONNUM>0</REVISIONNUM>
               <POID>286</POID>
            </PO>
         </X1POSet>
      </SyncX1POResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you checked with your team or service provider for the same?

Comment: I'm the only one having this problem.

Comment: Is that a public web service?

Comment: What do you mean public? I'm sorry I'm new to maximo integration. What I'm using is a web service specified to the enterprise service X1PO

Comment: This is fairly common in many webservices, regardless of Maximo. You are most likely adding the PO into the system. Maximo isn't going to tell you back everything you told it; you should already know that since you told it the information. What it does do is give you back the id/primary key of the newly created object, since that is usually all you need to supplement your data. You can then run a query service with that id to get back the full object and sub-objects if you really need that.

Comment: Okay, thanks! but is it possible to modify the response from maximo?

Comment: I can't recall if that insert response is modifiable. I believe the integration framework booklet for Maximo answers that question. The response from a query service is definitely modifiable though, so you need to be more clear about what you are asking. Also, does this mean you can't call the query service for some reason? And what additional information are you looking to get back and why?